# trigger in apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

Any one can tell me is there any Time based Trigger Policy available in Apache Ignite?

I Have an Object Having Expiry Date When That Date(Time-stamp) Expire I want to update This value and override it in Cache is it possible in Apache Ignite

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a time-based expiration policy in [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org) with eager TTL: [Expiry Policies](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies). This way objects will be eagerly expired from cache after a certain time.

Then you can subscribe a *javax.cache.event.CacheEntryExpiredListener*, which will be triggered after every expiration, and update the cache from that listener. However, it looks like there will be a small window when the entry will have been already expired from a cache and before you put and updated value into cache.

If the above window is not acceptable to you, then you can simply query all entries from a cache periodically and update all the entries that are older than a certain expiration time. In this case you would have to ensure that all entries have a timestamp filed, which will be indexed and used in SQL queries. Something like this:

SELECT * from SOME_TYPE where timestamp > 2;

More on SQL queries here: [Distributed Queries](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries), [Local Queries](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/local-queries).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
cache.withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 123))).put(k, v);
```

The expiration will be applied only to this entry.

For trigger try continuous queries: [apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries](https://try%20continuous%20queries:%20apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries)